# How to export connection using Eclipse Remote System Explorer

Tags: eclipse, connection, export

How can I export every connection in RSE from an Eclipse installation to another? 
I can get it to export connection one by one but I cant't get it to export every connection at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can't just copy your profile info from workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rse.core/profiles/yourprofile/ to new setup. Can't copy passwords tho